# What is the complexity of C++ bitset constructor that converts from long?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, bitset, std-bitset

My guess is O(n) where n is the no. of bits. Or is it constant w.r.t. n? I mean it shouldn’t it just be able to copy the bits from memory?

Comment: I don't think there's any complexity specified, but O(n) sounds reasonable. And I'm a little curious about why are you asking? Is it just plain curiosity, or do you have a more concrete problem?

Comment: But `long` has a given number of bits fixed at compilation time, so what is the difference between O(n) and constant complexity if n is always the same number?

Comment: I'd assume it is constant as long as the bitset size is less than or equal to the size of `unsigned long long`

Comment: It could change depending on the implementation, so knowing about your compiler would help. As an example, [the source of the GNU STL](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html-3.4.6/bitset-source.html) shows that it is O(1).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was curious about its performance compared to making a bit array manually by dividing by 2.

Comment: I also think O(1), because the interal type is bounded to 64bit thus it should be a uint64_t.

Comment: @Foon: This definitely sounds like a premature optimization.

Comment: I'd assume that the actual content is stored as real memory bits (this justifies existence of `reference` member class), so compiler could simply copy contents of `long` to the memory occupied by `std::bitset`.

Comment: @Jaa-c DEFINITELY but I was feeling irritated for not finding a concrete answer.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen something similar is said here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/ under “val”

Comment: cpp.sh/5i3op It seems to be the case for GCC. `sizeof(std::bitset<64>)` is 8, `sizeof(std::bitset<65>)` is 16. I'd expect any sane compiler to do memcpy between int and the bitset (or optimize it and use registers).

Comment: @Foon I wouldn't trust the wording from cplusplus.com. But yes, it seems reasonable. I hope somebody will quote the standard to clarify it in answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, long has a fixed length, therefore copying it's contents is constant-time operation. On the other hand, you need to zero-out the rest of the bits in the bitset and that you are not able to do in less-than-linear time with respect to the length of the bit_set. So, In theory you cannot do better than O(n), where n is the length of the bitset.

I guess that from the asymptotical complexity point of view you can safely assume that the complexity of the constructor is the same as zeroing-out the allocated memory.

This analysis however has some value only for huge values of n and it does not make much sense to me to use a long constructor to initialize a bitset of million bits. So, if the size of the bitset is on the same scale as the size of long, it is practically constant-time.